# Connecting to sql server 2008 using vb

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

```
Function DBConnect()
Dim  vConnString, wfConnection, objConn
set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open Application("DB_CONNECT")    
set DBConnect = objConn
exit function
Response.Write("connected to Server 2008")
End Function    

Function GetValue()
Dim objCmd, objRS   
Set objCMD = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objRs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

With (objCMD) 
    .ActiveConnection = DBConnect()
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "select * from Acc.dbo.table"

    set ObjRS = .Execute()    
End With
 if err.number = 0 then
    if not objRs.EOF then
        arrData = objRs.GetRows 

        vDesc = arrData(5,0)
    else
        vDesc = vValue
    end if

    GetDescFromCode = True
end if
```

Response is Coming as

```
connected to Server 2008
```

While debuging, i got that its not going inside objRs.EOF if loop...any idea whats wrong

Comment: `.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` is wrong since you are not using an sp there. try `.CommandType = adCmdText`

Answer (score 0):

1. In DBConnect, check the status of objConn to make sure it's really being opened.
2. In DBConnect, you have `exit function` before `response.write`.
3. In GetValue, check value of err.number.

Comment: 1. Connection status is 1 and err.number is 0

Comment: Is objRs.EOF true or false?